# React-Leaflet React Component as Marker

Tags: reactjs, svg, react-leaflet

I've recently gotten into React Leaflet and from what I've gathered from the docs, it is not possible to add a custom React Element (Component or pure functional) as a marker.

What I want to achieve is to be able to use my React Element which is an SVG icon as the marker. This would be useful because I'll need to display several different color icons and it's way more convenient to pass the color as props and let React create the marker.

Am I right in assuming this isn't possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are incorrect!  :)  React-leaflet allows the creation of [custom components](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/master/docs/Extending.md#creating-custom-components).  Also, you should check out [react-leaflet-div-icon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-leaflet-div-icon) since it seems like it's exactly what you need.

Comment: I'm glad I was wrong. Seems like I completely misunderstood `react-leaflet-divicon` (I did stumble upon it previously). Thank you for your response!